# How to start recording a macro, using commandline mode?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, command-line, macro

If I wanted to start recording a macro using command-line mode, how would I do this?

Additionally, if I wanted to bind this action to a key, how would I do that in my `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question

```
:normal! qa
```

That would start recording a macro to the "a" register. You may change that to any lower case letter.

To map F3 to it, for example, you could use

```
noremap <F3> :normal! qz<CR>
```